# Python two Lists In two For Loops

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I have two list here:

```
list1 = [u'2018-05-06T15:53:05.000-0400', '2018-05-06T17:53:05.000-0400']

list2 = [u'2018-05-06T15:32:24.000-0400', u'2018-05-06T15:32:29.000-0400', u'2018-05-06T15:32:36.000-0400', u'2018-05-06T15:53:05.000-0400', u'2018-05-06T16:42:41.000-0400', u'2018-05-10T00:16:12.000-0400', u'2018-05-10T00:16:23.000-0400', u'2018-05-12T17:37:42.000-0400']
```

I'm trying to compare the elements in two lists and return the minimum value of the different for both element 0 in list1 and element 1 in list2, for example:

```
for value1 in list1:
    value1 = datetime.strptime(value1, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000-0400')
    for value2 in list2:
        value2 = datetime.strptime(value2, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000-0400')
        if value1 < value2:

            value3 = value2 - value1
            list3.append(value3)
 print list3
```

print list3 give me:

[datetime.timedelta(0, 2976), datetime.timedelta(3, 30187), datetime.timedelta(3, 30198), datetime.timedelta(6, 6277), datetime.timedelta(3, 22987), datetime.timedelta(3, 22998), datetime.timedelta(5, 85477)]

Everything in the same list.
Here in `list3[0]`, I could get the minimum value for first element in `list1` but how could I get the minimum value for the second one `list3[3]` and loop if i have element 3 in list1?

I would like to separate the list for compare result for first element in `list1` and second element, please let me know how to achieve this, much appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit better your question? Your code won't even work right now, given you can't subtract two strings. Provide an expected output for ex

Comment: Hi RafaelC, thanks for getting back to me, i have striptime conversion which convert unicode to datatime format and compare, i have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can separate your time deltas in different lists, and then just use `min` to get the minimum values.

Using your own code:

```
list3=[]
for value1 in list1:
    value1 = datetime.strptime(value1, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000-0400')
    aux_list = []
    for value2 in list2:
        value2 = datetime.strptime(value2, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000-0400')
        if value1 < value2:

            value3 = value2 - value1
            aux_list.append(value3)
    list3.append(aux_list)
```

This way, your `list3` holds the difference from each element of `list1` to all elements of `list2`

```
>>> print(list3)
[[datetime.timedelta(0, 2976), datetime.timedelta(3, 30187), datetime.timedelta(3, 30198), datetime.timedelta(6, 6277)], 
 [datetime.timedelta(3, 22987), datetime.timedelta(3, 22998), datetime.timedelta(5, 85477)]]
```

Then you can get the minimum difference from the first item using `min(list[0])` and for the second `min(list[1])`

---

Notice that, if you have

```
l1 = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000-0400') for x in list1]
l2 = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000-0400') for x in list2]
```

your whole code can be written in one line using list comprehension:

```
k = [min([v2 - v1 for v2 in l2 if v2>v1]) for v1 in l1]
```

being `l1` and `l2` your list of `datetime` objects. This yields

```
0:49:36 # k[0]
3 days, 6:23:07 # k[1]
```

Comment: Hey RafaelC, thanks so much for your input here:  aux_list = [] is the one i was trying to looking for, much appreciated !

Comment: Glad I could help :) !

Comment: Thanks Rafael, a side question, how do i sum the timedelta object in the  k list ? I could use k[0] + k[1], but what if i have more than 2 results, is there any function like sum() for the entire list ? I have tried that but got unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Yes @Wayne. Try `sum(list3[0], datetime.timedelta())`

Comment: my result for list3 printed as:  [datetime.timedelta(0, 2976), datetime.timedelta(3, 22987)] then when i use sum(list3, datetime.timedelta()), i got error object type datetime.datetime has no attribute 'timedelta', in the list it obviously shows timedelta, but why it indicate as datetime in the error message

Comment: The error is raised because you probably wrote `from datetime import datetime`. But `timedelta()` is accessed directly in `datetime` module. So, if you do `import datetime` and then `datetime.timedelta()` should work :)

Comment: Then i got this 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime', i think i should import time as well

Comment: You should import `datetime` and use the full name everywhere else, i.e. `datetime.datetime.strptime` and `datetime.timedelta()`

Comment: really appreciated your time and detailed explanation here, it finally works like charm !

Answer (score 0):

First off, Python doesn't know that the string represents a date. You can't just throw data into a string and expect the interpreter to know what you want. So, you're just going to get an error because the "-" operator means nothing to strings.

If you want to compare two dates, I suggest reading up on Python's builtin datetime module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, i have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the two lists together you can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them and iterate over them simultaneously.  Then compare the values and append the one you want to the result list.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [0, 3]
list3 = []
for (x, y) in zip(list1, list2):
    z = min(x, y) 
    list3.append(z)
```

Note that the result will be the size of the smaller list, list2 in this case.